# Is there a stand-alone CSS layout framework that works like layout in AngularJS Material?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, layout, angular-material

I really like the way layout works in AngularJS Material.

However I have to use a different CSS framework.

Does anyone know of a stand-alone CSS framework just for layout that works like layout in AngularJS Material?

Comment: why don't you just grab the portion you like? and with `layout` you mean `grid`?

Comment: I'm talking about layout="row" and layout="column" and related directives. I think it's AngularJS directives in addition to CSS. I have found something standalone that looks similar, but it only works for AngularJS 2.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax isn't going to be exactly the same, but the layout options in Angular Material are based on Flexbox, which is part of CSS3. I'd recommend just implementing it yourself. There's a good guide here: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.